# Reference request on spherical harmonics

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian, spherical-harmonics

I'd like to find a (hopefully modern, mathematician-friendly) reference which proves that homogeneous harmonic polynomials restrict to an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ functions on the sphere $S^n$. Particularly I'd like to understand why we should expect that harmonic functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ restrict to eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on the sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chapter 5 of Harmonic Function Theory by Axler, Bourdon and Ramey](https://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf). As with any Axler book, it's a very thorough treatment of harmonic polynomials with a fair bit of motivation.